# Can't connect Client to other gateway when DNS is set to domain controller

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, client-server

I recently configured an active directory and connected the clients via network connection settings by setting the DNS for the domain controller.
But people who want to work in home office can't connect to their own gateway at home, since the network adapter settings are used for all networks.

How can I tell Windows 10 to use a different network adapter setting for the internal network but search the DNS server address automatically when using another network?

**Edit**:
Yes, the machines are set up to use DHCP.
The DNS server address is manually inserted into the network adapter option. Until now there was only one client with this issue (the addc has less than 20 clients). I assume that's because people are normally using wlan at home and ethernet at work.
[This is the IPv4 setting, so the client can find the DC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdEBR.png) (sorry, even if my pc is set in english, it displays these settings in my native language)

Comment: Can you provide more details. Are these machines are setup to use DHCP? Do they come to office and can work, but when they go back to home, they can no longer work?

Comment: @AbuZaid I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to assign DNS from the DHCP server, this way, when they are in the office, they get Domain Controller as DNS. When they go back home, they will get DNS server from the Home Network DHCP (like an ISP Router or Modem).

Comment: I can't install a DHCP onto a Domain Controller, can I?

Comment: You can, that shouldn't be a problem at all. The only time you would not do it, if you have a very large number of Computers, Sites and Users, in that case dedicated DHCP Sever will be used.